# Cannot install spl-token-sli - error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Signature` in crate `signature`

Tags: spl-token, installation

When I try to install `spl-token-sli` using command `cargo install spl-token-cli`.
I get this error:

```
error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Signature` in crate `signature`
   --> /home/marek/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ed25519-1.5.2/src/lib.rs:335:17
    |
335 | impl signature::Signature for Signature {
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `signature`
```

I'm using Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon. I have tried to delete .cargo folder and reinstall Rust, but same error.

Comment: try ```impl Signature for Signature``` instead of ```impl signature::Signature for Signature```. Does it work?

Comment: @AbdullahQureshi Yes, that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference to others facing the same problem:

try `impl Signature for Signature` instead of `impl signature::Signature for Signature`

Comment: Can you elaborate why this change is needed for end-user who just wants to install the spl-token-cli? Is it bug? Or some incompatibility?

Comment: since the import trait already exists in the target modules. For further understating you can read a similar error explanation at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55026.